how to divide $a^{n-1} x^n+x((-1)^n+a^n)+a^{n-1}$ by $ax+1$?
I need to find $a(n,k)$ where
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a(n,k) x^k=\frac{1}{a^n+(-1)^n}\frac{a^{n-1} x^n+x((-1)^n+a^n)+a^{n-1}}{ax+1}$$
where I need it to find a general partial fraction form
$$ \frac{x}{(x^n+1)(ax+1)} =\frac{1}{x^n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a(n,k) x^k - \frac{1}{ax+1}\frac{a^{n-1}}{a^n+(-1)^n} $$

The successive terms of the quotient by simple long division are
$$a^{n-2}x^{n-1}-a^{n-3}x^{n-2}+a^{n-4}x^{n-3}-\cdots.....$$ Take care at the end of the procedure.

@Piquito So is it $$ a^{n-1} x^n +x ((-1)^n+a^n) +a^{n-1}=(ax+1) \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  (-1)^{n-k-1} a^{k-1}x^k $$ ?

For coprime polynomials $f(t)$, $g(t)$, $t-b$, we have the identity
$$\frac{f(t)}{g(t)(t-b)}
= \frac{f(b)}{g(b)}\cdot\frac{1}{t-b}
+\left(f[t,b] - \frac{g[t,b]f(b)}{g(b)}\right)
  \frac{1}{g(t)}$$
where
$\phi[u,v]=\tfrac{\phi(u)-\phi(v)}{u-v}$ denotes the divided difference. So let $b=-1$, $f(t)=a^{n-1}t$, $g(t)=t^n + a^n$, $t=ax$. Then
$$\frac{x}{(x^n+1)(ax+1)}
= -\frac{a^{n-1}}{(-1)^n+a^n}\cdot\frac{1}{ax+1}
+a^{-1}\left(1 + \frac{h_{n-1}(ax,-1)}{(-1)^n+a^n}\right)
  \frac{1}{x^n+1}$$
where
$$h_{n-1}(u,v) = \frac{u^n-v^n}{u-v}$$
is the complete symmetric polynomial of degree $n-1$ in two variables (a terminating geometric series).

but $h_{n-1}(ax,-1)=\frac{(ax)^n-(-1)^n}{ax+1}$ So we still have the form $\frac{1}{(x^n+1)(ax+1)}$

@Faoler no, $h_{n-1}$ is a polynomial, one whose identity you can look up
